# Method creation dilemma

Tags: c#, .net, methods, system, il

I have new problem. I need to make returntype parameter free method with list of arguments.
Code:

```
Builder.DefineMethod("aaa", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);
```

This is my code. Best overload for me is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbwdt101.aspx

So now the question: 
How can I make method without return parameters which can get arguments?
(I need something what can do this:
`Builder.DefineMethod("aaa", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, Type[] ArgumentTypes`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `null` for the return type:

```
Builder.DefineMethod("aaa", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, null, yourArgumentTypes);
```

**UPDATE**

Decompiling the TypeBuilder, it looks like the overloads without a return type pass `null` to the larger overloads, so it looks like `null` is the way the overloads without a return type indicate no return type.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Looking at the decompiled code, the smaller overloads pass `null` to the larger ones for return type.

Comment: Interesting.  I've always used `typeof(void)`, but experimenting with both produced the same results.  Technically, `typeof(void)` is more accurate in the sense that once you've defined the method, the value returned from the `ReturnType` property will be `System.Void` (aka, `typeof(void)`).  (But since they both produce the same effect, this difference is obviously academic)

Comment: @KirkWoll: True.  I can see both making semantic sense.  It's probably good that they allow either.